# Wicked exceptions behavior using the `exceptions` package

Tags: haskell

I have been taken aback by some peculiar behavior while using the `exceptions` package.

I have a function that looks like:

```
testme ::(MonadThrow m , Monad O m, Applicative m) => FilePath -> Text -> m ()
testme fp t = testfoo fp t >> testbar fp t
```

with

```
testfoo :: (MonadThrow m , MonadIO m, Applicative m) => FilePath -> Text -> m ()
testbar :: (MonadThrow m , MonadIO m, Applicative m) => FilePath -> Text -> m ()
```

Another module will catch all the specific exceptions thrown here doing something along the line:

```
catching _PrettyError
         (do {testCatalog workingdir c; return stm})
         (return . S.Left)
```

And _PrettyError is defined as such:

```
_PrettyError :: Prism' SomeException PrettyError
_PrettyError = prism' toException fromException
```

My first surprise comes from the fact that if I change `testme` for:

```
testme = testfoo  >> testbar
```

Ghc refuses to compile because it can't deduce MonadThrow.

Trying this signature:

```
testme :: FilePath -> Text -> IO ()
testme = testfoo >> testbar
```

Ghc still don't want to deduce `MonadThrow` which I find more surprising.

I am now making another type signature change:

```
testfoo :: FilePath -> Text -> IO ()
testbar :: FilePath -> Text -> IO ()
```

And ... it does compile but in utter bewilderment I have then realized that only the exceptions from the second call (testbar) would be caught by `catching`.
The ones throws by `testfoo` are just lost somehow ...

I am amazed that changing signatures would completely change the exception handling.

[The commit of the real code is here](https://github.com/bartavelle/language-puppet/commit/f9f8b8b70ed055125bee5ef6426badcf01f66cd6) (with notes).

The current code does work as expected.

My question is really why the signature change from explicit constraints to a specific IO monad causes such an unexpected behavior (the exceptions from the first term of `>>` aren't caught anymore). My understanding is that in both case the `IO` monad is at play.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should definitely use a properly-endowed exception monad transformer rather than relying on IO.  That said, the behavior you are seeing is pretty weird

Comment: I am actually relying on the `exceptions` package trying to follow [these principles](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/DanBurton/test-upload-group/content/exceptions-best-practices).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably meant `testme fp t = testfoo fp t >> testbar fp t` instead of `testme = testfoo >> testbar`. In the latter, the `(>>)` is from the `(->) r` instance, which is what's surprising you: `f >> g` is the same as just `g` for the `(->) r` monad (but makes your computer a little hotter).

Comment: Yes I have forgotten the testfoo ... I will edit my question.

Comment: @PierreR I would give the same answer to your edited question (up to the renamings you gave in your edit).

Comment: I actually thought `testCatalog fp t = testFileSources fp t >> testUsersGroups fp t` was equivalent to `testCatalog = testFileSources >> testUsersGroups` ... So this could be my problem all along ...

Comment: Yep I have just checked it. My confusion has born from the fact that I have always assumed it was equivalent with or without the params ...Thanks so much !